# Problem with the output of a cmd command in java

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to read in the results of a cmd command (dir for example). After creating the process, I use a `BufferedReader` in conjunction with an `InputStreamReader`.  For some reason, the `BufferedReader` keeps coming up empty, even though I know that there must be some output to be read.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
String[] str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", 
            "cd", "c:\\",
            "dir", "/b", "/s"               
    };
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try{

        Process p = rt.exec(str);
        InputStream is =p.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(is.available());
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line = buff.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while( line != null )
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line);
            line = buff.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println( sb );
        if ( sb.length() != 0 ){
            File f = new File("test.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());

            fos.close();
        }
    }catch( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: is process.getErrorStream() also returning empty?

Comment: yes - both the ErrorStream and InputStream have 0 bytes available

Comment: I just ran it again, and the error stream is not empty. When I read the error stream, it printed "The system cannot find the path specified," which doesn't exactly make sense, but at least it's something.

Comment: Try to force the physical address of the file, `C:\\test.txt` and see what happens

Comment: Well it could mean that cmd.exe is not in the PATH (or %PATH%, or whatever it's called on windows). 
Can you try using the full path to the executable, at least for a start ?

Comment: I tried using cmd.exe before, and it worked, so I don't think it's a problem with the %PATH% variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got:

```
String[] str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", 
            "cd", "c:\\",
            "dir", "/b", "/s"               
    };
```

which doesn't seem right to me.  You can't put multiple commands to cmd.exe on one command line.  Thats a batch file.

Try getting rid of everything either the cd or the dir.

edit: indeed:

```
C:\>cmd.exe /c cd c:\ dir
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: That solved the problem! I put an "&" between the cd command and the dir command and got the correct output!

Comment: @chama: What about simply using `dir /b /s C:\​`? Just for the fun of it: Try running your code from another drive, such as `D:`. Your `cd` command would do nothing there. Generally, use whatever is applicable and don't try to overcomplicate things. This is an example where you need exactly one command which will do what you want. That sequence of two won't.

Answer (score 1):

There could be an error. In this case you should also trap getErrorStream()

Comment: I tried trapping the ErrorStream and got "The system cannot find the path specified." But how can it not find c:\?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are running is `cmd.exe /c cd c:\ dir /b /s`. I don't think that's doing what you expect.

---

I mean that you have concatenated two commands into one line and the Windows shell probably doesn't like that. Try something like

```
String[] str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", 
            "cd", "c:\\", "&&",
            "dir", "/b", "/s"               
    };
```

The `&&` will tell the shell to execute `cd c:\` and then to execute `dir /b /s` if the first command was successful.

Comment: that's a very good point. I was originally searching for a certain file in that folder.  Unfortunately, taking out the /s didn't solve the problem