# use java to make severals cmd commands

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, rman

Hi i'm trying to make a backup using rman from java, im trying using a Runtime from java, im able to open the cmd, access rman but after that any other query i try to submit is executed.
im able to access rman from cmd window and sqlplus window
i alredy tried using ; and without it
here's the code, please help me:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
         command[0] = "cmd";
         command[1] = "/c";
         command[2] = "rman target / catalog rman/rman@xe;";
         command[3] = "backup as backupset database plus archivelog;";
         command[4] = "exit;";
         command[5] = "sqlplus.exe;";
         try {  
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String line = reader.readLine();
         while (line != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
             line = reader.readLine();
         }
```

And this is the output:

```
Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Lun Nov 11 22:11:12 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: XE (DBID=2711152663)
connected to recovery catalog database
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Problem with the output of a cmd command in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201513/problem-with-the-output-of-a-cmd-command-in-java) ...specifically if you have multiple commands that you are wanting `cmd` to execute you have to use the `&` symbol to join them together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run commands as if you were in an "interactive" session, you will need to spawn "cmd.exe", then use `p.getOutputStream()` to "write" commands to execute.

Something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
writer.println("rman target / catalog rman/rman@xe;");
writer.println("backup as backupset database plus archivelog;");
writer.println("exit;");
writer.println("sqlplus.exe;");
```

**Note:** if you don't read the `p.getInputStream()` between commands you will likely block.

Comment: i did it as you told me and now i just have access to cmd :(

Comment: Try adding /k to the ProcessBuilder, e.g. ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/k").